# How can I debug my Java code?

Tags: java

```
public class night {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(addition(1,1,1,1));
}

public static int addition (int...numberz){

    int total=0;

    for(int x=1; x<=numberz.length; x++) {
        total+=x;
    }
    return total;
  }
}
```

The above code doesn't add the numbers correctly.

When I use an enhanced for loop in the method "addition", I get desired results:-

```
public static int addition (int...numberz){

    int total=0;

    for(int x:numberz) {
        total+=x;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Please answer in as simple terms as you can, as to why the first code doesn't work, and the second one does.

### Edit

I had no idea the ellipsis turned the variable "numberz" into an array.

Comment: this  total+=x; is doing a summatory series...

Comment: In the first version you are adding the counter values, not the actual values, change it to `total+=numberz[x];`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with using loop. These are:

- You are adding index i.e. `x`, instead of *value at the index* i.e. `numberz[x]`. So change the line `total+=x;` to `total+= numberz[x];`
- You need to change the loop from `for(int x=1; x<=numberz.length; x++)` to `for(int x=0; x<numberz.length; x++)`.

Following is corrected code. See it working [here](https://ideone.com/Jj9MbT):

```
public class night {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(addition(1,1,1,1));
    }

    public static int addition (int...numberz){

        int total=0;

        for(int x=1; x<numberz.length; x++) {
            total+= numberz[x];
        }
        return total;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should access the array in your first for-loop

```
public static int addition (int...numberz){

    int total=0;

    for(int x=1; x<=numberz.length; x++) {

        total+=numberz[x]; // <--- here

    }

        return total;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

this loop is wrong

```
for(int x=1; x<=numberz.length; x++) {
    total+=x;
}
```

because is adding the indices of the arrays and not the values pointed at...

you need the value in the array not its index:

```
for(int x=1; x<=numberz.length; x++) {
    total+=numberz[x];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the for loop for the first one:

```
for(int x=1; x<=numberz.length; x++) {

        total+=x;

}
```

Here you are not adding the numbers from `numberz` array, rather than you are starting index x from 1 and summing it into total variable. Actual implementation should look like this:

```
for(int x=0; x < numberz.length; x++) {

        total+=numberz[x];

}
```

x started from 0, because array index start's from 0.

Answer (score 0):

In the first loop, the result is 10, as every time you are adding the value of x, so the code runs like 0+1,1+1.... so on.

```
  for(int x=1; x<=numberz.length; x++) {

        total+=x;

    }
```

As the numberez is an integer array you have to get the index of it from 0-->3 as array starts from 0.

```
  for(int x=0; x<numberz.length; x++) {
            total+=numberz[x];
        }
```

This will gives you the 4 as the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println(addition(1,1,1,1));
}

public static int addition (int...numberz){

  int total=0;

for(int x=1; x<=numberz.length; x++) {
    total+=x;
}
    return total;
 }
}
```

> instead of using

```
 for(int x=1; x<=numberz.length; x++) {
    total+=x;
 }
```

> try this

```
   for(int x=0; x<numberz.length; x++) 
   {
        total=total+numberz[x];
   }
```

> Thank you..!!